Use geometry nodes to instance object in conical shape
How can I rotate each of the instanced meshes using geometry nodes to form a conical shape like the example on the left?


Make a tilt first, then use the position in the circle to rotate in Z:


oh ok, Rotate Instances is what I needed, although I don't see why you're calling that before Instance on Points, I tried the opposite and it worked as expected.

No specific reason... just did. I sort of thought that the instances would have their own rotation after being placed and that I would need a different rotation axis for each.

@Bugbeeb Well, there actually is or there could be a difference if you do the Rotate Instances before or after the Instance on Points: before, the geometry is in its original position so it won't matter if the Local Space option is enabled or not, it would also work in global space since at the start local space is equal to global space. But after instancing on points it is mandatory to use Local Space in order to get this result. Since it's enabled in the given nodetree, the position before or after does not matter as you found out.

@Bugbeeb However, the other thing is, it is completely unnecessary to use a Geometry to Instance node here: you only need it if you use Rotate Instances before Instance on Points, when rotating the instances afterwards it would work with the following setup as well and so you need less nodes: simplified nodetree

Using the logic of Daniel, which I like, you can use "Transform Geometry" node to rotate the starting geometry, then instance it. I think you can also use "Curve Circle", then "Curve to Points" and take the "Rotation" from there.

@MarkusvonBroady Sure, there are many different ways to create the desired result. Only the Geometry to Instance node is not needed, it is just necessary to convert the base mesh to an instance because otherwise the Rotate Instances node would not work on it - but as you said, a Transform Geometry node could be used instead.
